# How to make a table with count of each category

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table with two columns. One is Name, other is Mark.
Mark can be low, mid or high. Under every name, i want count of high low and mid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX7H2.png)

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not use a `SELECT` query for this?

Comment: So from doing this i get it as 3 separate row enteries each for high mid and low. Can it be so that for one name their be 3 columns each of high low and mid so that there is only one entry for one name

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Mark = 'low' THEN 1 END) AS low_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Mark = 'mid' THEN 1 END) AS mid_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Mark = 'high' THEN 1 END) AS high_count
FROM
    DesiredTable
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

Description:

1. **`SELECT`** Clause:

   - **`Name`:** Column that holds the names of individuals.
   - **`COUNT(CASE WHEN Mark = 'low' THEN 1 END) AS low_count:`** An aggregation using the ***`COUNT`*** function combined with a ***`CASE`*** statement. It counts the occurrences where the value in the `Mark` column is 'low' for each unique Name. The result of this count is given an alias ***`low_count`***.
   - Same for ***`mid`*** and ***`high`***.
2. **`FROM`** Clause:

   - **`DesiredTable`:** Source table from which the data is being fetched and processed.
3. **`GROUP BY`** Clause:

   - **`Name`:** Results are grouped based on the unique values in the `Name` (`Distinct`) column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, mark, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name, mark
```

**Edit** to answer question from comment: sure, but it can not be dynamic without making it much more complex. That means you must explicitly define each column before the query is executed:

```
SELECT name
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'Low') Low
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'Mid') Mid
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'High') High
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: So from doing this i get it as 3 separate row enteries each for high mid and low. Can it be so that for one name their be 3 columns each of high low and mid so that there is only one entry for one name

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL?

```sql
SELECT     name, 
           count(mark)
FROM       your_table
GROUP BY   name, 
           mark
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is counting and *pivoting* results. First off pivoting is best left to your app's presentation manager as with SQL it is necessary to actually list each element value of interest and any change requires the query to be rewritten. It may not be too bad with 3-5 possibilities, but 30-50 becomes a different story.  

However, with that out the way, what you are looking for is *conditional aggregation*. For this you `count(column)` for each desired values. This is accomplished with the [FILTER predicate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). Query becomes something like:

```
Select name
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'low')  "Low_Marks" 
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'mid')  "Mid_Marks" 
     , count(mark) filter (where mark = 'high') "High_Marks" 
  from some_table 
 group by name 
 order by name;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested, no data supplied, I cannot process an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE Name = t.Name AND Mark = 'high') AS high_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE Name = t.Name AND Mark = 'mid') AS mid_count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE Name = t.Name AND Mark = 'low') AS low_count
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY Name;
```

Run this command hope this will help you.